# JasperReports How to add docx footer and header

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, docx, docx4j

I need to inject a header and footer to a jasper report in order to edit a document.

I know that Jasper prints tables in a docx including the footer and header causing an static non native document.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was impossible to add native header and footer to a jasper report.

It renders a table per page, if you select all document and enable all boundaries you notice of it.

Maybe you could first create an excel and export your result using docx4j.

http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j

There are ASPOSE for Jasperreports but I didn't tried it.

Cheers!